# about degenerate and pseudoinverses

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

I am reading functional analysis writes by Peter  D Lax.

I am confuse about a exercise in his book

Definition1: a linear map G is called degenerate if its range is finite dimensional

Definition2:the linear maps M:$X\rightarrow  U$ and L:$U \rightarrow X$ are pseudoinverse$ to each other if LM=I+G,ML=I+G,where I denotes the identity ,G degenerate maps of $X\rightarrow X$,and $U\rightarrow U$,respectively.

Exercise if L and M are pseudoinverse of each other ,so are $L+G_1$and $M+G_2$,where $G_1,G_2$ are arbitrary degenerate maps.

Proof $(L+G_1)(M+G_2)=LM+LG_1+G_1M+G_1G_2$

And LM=I+G,and $G+LG_1+G_1M+G_1G_2$
Is degenerate ,so we are done .is my proof right?

But I can’t understand the second question

Suppose that M:$X\rightarrow U$and A:$U\rightarrow W$have pseudoinverses L and B respectively .then AM and LB are pseudoinverse to each other.

I can’t understand how AM contact LB ..am I understand the question wrongly?

Why LAX’s book proof so little,can you give me another book about functional analysis for new learner

Comment: Your first  answer is correct. For the second question, write down what it means that $A$ and $B$ are pseudoinverses and the same for $L$ and $M$. Then compute $(LB) \circ (AM) = L \circ (BA)  \circ M$ and use the definitions.

Comment: @HansEngler what \circ means?